# Question regarding PCB architecture

Tags: voltage, power, pcb, ac, ground

I am just starting to understand the EVSE architecture and how it will be on the PCB.

Hence, I went through this [teardown video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kqkEr93NjDg&t=165s) to understand the PCB architecture.

Picture:

[image]

(I saw that in some questions, sharing videos is not recommended. But I searched on Google to find answers. But failed. Hence asking here).

My objective is to:

1. Understand how the main AC wires that are coming as input to the PCB, are getting converted into traces on the PCB?

There are three sets of wires.

One from the input power mains.

Two (middle) current tranformer

Three - Ouptut AC power.

The input AC wire is incoming to the PCB and output AC power wires is taken from different wires. Since there's no direct wire between input and output, the AC input is converted into some signal traces and then it is processed and then given to the output wires.

But my question is where should the input wires end in the PCB and from where should the output power traces get converter into the output power wires? I see some terminal screws on the PCB. Only from there the input wires terminate. And from the other set of screw terminals, the output wires comes.

But from which peripheral or places should the traces come so that the traces get changed to wires from the screw terminals?

Comment: Can you post a picture. It's hard to understand what are you asking. Is this about how a screw terminal takes in a wire and converts it to PCB trace?

Comment: These are three explicitly numbered topics (already two too many, strictly speaking), but each of them is so broad that one needs to explain a lot of basics until one can actually just address them. So, your whole post here is by far not focused enough. If recommend this: delete the second and third part of your post. From the remaining first part, actually focus on one simple question. For example, "*I want to understand the current for on this particular PCB (and actually add a photo of that PCB); I've analyzed to the best of my knowledge which side attaches to the grid but I'm unclear*...

Comment: ... *about what the role of transformer T1 is, seeing that, to my understanding, this is DC.*" Ask about **one** topic, don't jump to conclusions, and where you make assumptions, clearly state them. In its current form, your question is really too broad to be answered.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, sure, will ask only the first question here and the remaining two questions in separate post.

Comment: @Justme, edited this question. Can you please check once?

Comment: Impossible to tell without a schematic, but all EV charger boxes work the same, just pass though of the AC via relay and RCB. Routing 16 A current in a PCB requires somewhat wide traces but nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: @Freshman Sounds like you want to understand how the device works, but still stuck on how wire gets converted to PCB tracks, instead of trying to understand at higher level how electricity goes through various components? Turn the board upside down and trace the PCB tracks to see how the wiring goes.

Comment: @Justme, Yes, that's also true. I want to understand how the device works. But stuck on how wire gets converted to PCB tracks where and why? I do not have the physical board with me. Hence, finding it difficult. Can you help with it

Answer (score 1):

A PCB trace is just a very flat sort of wire.  There isn't any "conversion" required.  The screw terminals will be soldered to the PCB traces.

The input supply shouldn't be connected straight to the output.  In an EVSE, the output power isn't turned on until the EVSE has detected that there's a car plugged in.  The power is going through the relays instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, the screw terminals will be soldered on to the PCB traces. 1. In that case, what should the maximum size of those traces (is the maximum current 16A, as the connector mentioned in the video is J1772?). Also, 2. There are wires into the CT in the middle section of the board (see picture), right? Where would the start and end point would those be? If you could, just draw a sample diagram with mentions of where the wires and where the traces should be in the PCB, it would really help me with the understanding.