# Separate grounds for AC main and Low voltage

Tags: voltage, power, pcb, ac, ground

This question is with regard to or a follow up question of this one over [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/672950/question-regarding-pcb-architecture).

Request you to refer to the picture in that question.

My question is:

Since we have high voltage (AC mains input) and low voltage (MCU peripherals), should any from of separate ground isolation is required? If so, can somene tell me which peripherals should have the AC mains ground and which peripherals should have the digital low voltage ground and which would be the ideal location to connect these two grounds together?

Thank you.